# Product in red after adding cocoapod to a mac target

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, product, target

There are other questions on SO but none solves my case.

After adding a cocoapod to my Mac target, the app product is now shown in red.

This is my config:

1. Xcode is building the product to the following directory

   **~Library/Developer/DerivedData/MyApp-adsjfhgajdfgajhdgfjahgdf/Build/Products/Debug/**
2. Per-configuration Build Products Path = **build**
3. Per-configuration intermediate Build Files Path = **$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)**

How do I fix that?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction at the CocoaPods site? Hint, you don't add a CocoaPod to your current target but to a workspace.

Comment: yes, the pod is added to the cocoa target on the workspace.